# How to use DialogResult with javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to show a message box with OkCancel buttons from my aspx page.
It can be possible with code behind code

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("How are you?", "Hi",MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
```

But I want to do this with Javascript or jQuery is it possible?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**confirm**](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/vPyQN/)**

```
var r = confirm("Press a button");
if (r == true) {
    alert("You pressed OK!");
}
else {
    alert("You pressed Cancel!");
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

With plain javascript you could use the [`prompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.prompt) function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var result = window.prompt('How are you?');
    alert(result);
</script>
```

If you want to have more control over the visual aspect of this dialog you will have to build it manually because browsers do not allow any customizations of those windows. For example you could use the [`jQuery UI dialog`](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) plugin. Take a look at the [`modal form demo`](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) which allows you to have complete control over the visual aspect of the dialog box.